# Can hibernating my laptop damage further my already damaged hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, hibernate, mode

For the past year, I have been hibernating my laptop everyday (along with weekly shutdowns) and recently my hard drive got damaged which resulted to the notorious reboot loop. I just got it repaired discovering 1000+ bad sectors in it during the repair process. The technician advised me against hibernating my laptop as it may add to the strain the hard drive is already handling. Is this true?

Edit: The technician only did an "HDD Recovery Program" on my hard drive which only took about an hour to complete.

Comment: Yes;  Its true.  The more you write to the HDD the more bad sectors will be discovered.  As more and more bad sectors are discovered if a system file is moved, and then that sector goes bad, you will lose that file and your system no longer boots.

Comment: Hibernation isn't the problem, a failing hard drive is.  If the amount of writing done by hibernation will make a difference, you're in deep yogurt.  If the drive is on the verge of imminent death, the only activity you want to do with it is getting you stuff off and onto a good drive.  In that case, don't push your luck with hibernation.  If the drive is good enough to rely on as a working drive, hibernation won't make a difference.  1000+ bad sectors doesn't sound like a trustworthy drive.  In your case, I not only wouldn't hibernate, I wouldn't use it until you off-load the contents.

Comment: I've just finished a back up of my files (didn't include a system image because the hard drive I was using to back up didn't have sufficient space for one). I guess since I'm done with backing it up, I should start using it as I normally would and wait for its inevitable death?

Comment: @Benjamin You *could* do that, yes. However, any files on the HDD might get corrupted. So you should be **extremely** careful when copying any of these files to your good backup disk. It could happen that you overwrite some good files with broken ones! My advice would be to buy a new disk and retire the broken one rather sooner than later.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: probably **yes**, if the hard drive is already old or slightly damaged. Probably **no**, if the hard drive is healthy and new.

Long answer:
When hibernating your Laptop, all data that lies in the RAM gets written to the hard drive (so the state of your computer is stored similarly to a mere "suspend" [to RAM]).

That means each time you hibernate, some amount of data is written to your hard drive (several 100MiB to several GiB). If your hard drive is healthy, this should not matter (hard drives are MADE to store data).

However, I can think of 2 scenarios where hibernating CAN actually be detrimental to the life of your hard disk:

- If your hard drive has defect sectors where it wants to write the hibernation-data, the internal HDD-controller will re-map those sectors to some of the HDD's reserved sectors. Therefore, the amount of unused reserved sectors will decrease. Since you don't have too many of those reserved sectors, one day you will run out (sooner rather than later!). If that happens, you REALLY need to replace your hard disk ASAP.
- In general, if you physically move your laptop - and therefore the hard drive within - while it is running (especially when reading/writing data to disk, as you do when entering the hibernation state). The vibration and other forces applied can cause write-errors on the disk (bad for your data itself) or even physical damage on the write-read head or on the platters of the hard drive themselves (which is really bad for your drive). Seeing many people that just press "hibernation" and immediately throw the laptop into their backpack, I can see how that might damage the hard drive.

That being said: If your hard disk starts showing up a lot of bad sectors, its best to replace it right now while all data is still readable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm backing up my hard drive as we speak so that I'll be ready when the time comes when it will really fail on me.